# Active directory access and IIS Authetication method issue

Tags: c#, active-directory, iis-7.5

I have an intranet application that authenticates users against active directory. In general it works fine when testing locally(i.e. from my dev machine using VS 2017) or running it off of IIS in app server ("Browse *:80") until I try to access it using its URL from my local machine. Then whatever user id I use to get user's detail info, nothing is displayed.

Also, this app is to be accessible to users in certain groups so application checks logged in user's group membership.

Here is how I have it set up in IIS and different scenarios I tested with:

- I set authentication to "Windows Authentication", disabled anonymous
  authentication and enabled AS.NET Impersonation. This works fine when
  running from app server using localhost but when trying to access
  from my local machine and supplying user's user id to get his/her
  detail info, no details are displayed (fails to get any info from
  AD).
- If I enable anonymous authentication and set it to "Application Pool    Identity" (i.e. Network Services), it displays my custom
  "Access Denied"    page, presumably because this user is not part of
  allowed group.
- If I enable anonymous authentication and select "Specific User",      supplying my credentials, then everything works fine, from app server or from my local machine, with one caveat: no matter who is accessing the site, it shows my name as logged in user.

I am stumped ad would appreciate some hints.

**Update - Added code to get user info**

Code to get user's identity:

```
WindowsIdentity wiUser = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
string sID = wiUser.Name.ToUpper();
```

Code to get user's AD info:

```
static string adDomain = "www.xxx.yyy.zzz";
static string adContainer = "DC=www,DC=xxx,DC=yyy,DC=zzz";

public static DataTable getUserADInfoDT(string sSearchStr)
{
    DataTable dtResults = new DataTable();
    dtResults.Columns.Add("ID");
    dtResults.Columns.Add("FirstName");
    ...
    dtResults.Columns.Add("Zip");

    string adDomain = string.Empty;
    string adContainer = string.Empty;

    // create domain context
    PrincipalContext adPrincipalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, adDomain, adContainer);

    using (adPrincipalContext)
    {
        // define a "query-by-example" principal 
        UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(adPrincipalContext);
        qbeUser.SamAccountName = sSearchStr.Trim().ToUpper();

        // create principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
        PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);
        PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> psr = srch.FindAll();

        // find all matches
        foreach (var found in psr)
        {
            DataRow dr = dtResults.NewRow();
            UserPrincipal up = (UserPrincipal)found;
            DirectoryEntry de = (DirectoryEntry)up.GetUnderlyingObject();

            dr["ID"] = de.Properties["SAMAccountName"].Value.ToString().ToUpper(); 

            if (de.Properties["givenName"].Value != null) 
                dr["FirstName"] = de.Properties["givenName"].Value.ToString();

            ...

            if (de.Properties["postalCode"].Value != null)
                dr["Zip"] = de.Properties["postalCode"].Value.ToString();

            dtResults.Rows.Add(dr);
            //de.Close();
        }
        return dtResults;
    }
}
```

Comment: Let's ignore the second two scenarios you describe, since that's clearly not what you want. You need Windows Authentication enabled. Can you edit your question and add the code you use to check the user ID? I suspect that is the root of your problem.

Comment: That shows how you look up a username in AD. But where are you getting the value that you pass into the `sSearchStr` parameter? That's the important part I was talking about.

Comment: Edited previous edit and added couple of lines how to get user's identity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` will get the user account that the current process is running under. If the application is running in IIS, that will usually be the user account that the app pool is running under - not the user that logged in to your application.

If you use IIS Express for debugging locally, then IIS Express is running under your user account, so you wouldn't see a difference. But on the server you will.

That said, if you have impersonation turned on and working properly, then `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` should return the user that logged in - since impersonation means that your app is now pretending to be that person. So this might mean that impersonation isn't setup right. But maybe you don't even need it. I've never personally found a need to use impersonation.

To get the user that logged into your app, you should use `HttpRequest.Current.User` or possibly just `HttpContext.User` if your app is ASP.NET MVC.

And there is actually an easier way to get a `DirectoryEntry` object for the user, without having to search for the username. You can bind directly to the SID of the user, which is information you already have:

```
var user = new DirectoryEntry(
    $"LDAP://<SID={((WindowsIdentity) HttpContext.User.Identity).User.Value}>");
```

If your server is not joined to the same domain as your users, then you might need to include the domain name:

```
var user = new DirectoryEntry(
    $"LDAP://www.xxx.yyy.zzz/<SID={((WindowsIdentity) HttpContext.User.Identity).User.Value}>");
```

Something else to keep in mind: `DirectoryEntry` keeps a cache of all the `Properties`. When you access a property that it doesn't have in the cache already, it will go out to AD and ask for *every attribute with a value*. That's a lot of useless data going over the network if you only need 3 attributes. So you can tell it to specifically ask for only those 4 attributes before you use them:

```
user.RefreshCache(new[] {"SAMAccountName", "givenName", "postalCode"});
```

I talked about this, and other points, in an article I wrote: [Active Directory: Better Performance](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/12/15/better-performance-activedirectory.html)

*Update:* To verify if IIS is actually enforcing authentication for a page, you can do this in PowerShell (update the URL to what you need - and this requires at least PowerShell 3):

```
try { (Invoke-WebRequest "http://example.com/the/page").StatusCode }
    catch { $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.Value__}
```

That will output the status code of the reply. You *should* see `401`, since that is how IIS challenges the browser to send credentials. If you see `200`, then Windows Authentication is not working for that page.

I do this in PowerShell, since Chrome's dev tools won't even show you the 401 challenge.

Comment: I do have impersonation enabled and users, when they access the site, see their won user id and name on top of the page; so it must be working correctly. It is only when, in one of the pages, I try to access AD to get user's info, based on search by ID, that things go sideways. Also, when I try "string sID = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;" I get empty string.

Comment: That means they aren't authenticated then. Do you have anonymous authentication enabled either for the site or just that page? Or, if you're using MVC, are you using the `[Authorize]` attribute everywhere else except that page?

Comment: No, anonymous authentication is disabled, ASP.NET Impersonation and Windows Authentication are enable, and I am not using MVC.

Comment: Do you have any `<location>` tags in your web.config that could be changing the authentication for that specific page?

Comment: I have a couple of location tags in web.config but they only adjust maxrequestLength and executionTimeouts and none are related to the page in question.

Comment: I added an update to my answer to show how to test that IIS is actually enforcing authentication on that page.

Comment: I got it to work by wrapping AD search code in "using(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Impersonate());" However,I went through your article and made some changes, namely using Directorysearcher instead of UserPrincipal and restriction number of proprieties to return to only those I needed. I appreciate your assistance and pointing in the right direction. i marked your response as the answer.

Comment: Now, only if I knew why the downvote for the question so I wouldn't repeat it.

Comment: Sounds good. I'm glad I could help a little bit. Although it's still curious why you'd need to impersonate to search AD. Is your server not joined to the domain?

Comment: The downvote wasn't me, but it was probably because you initially didn't include your code.

Comment: I think it is because of what you mentioned earlier: using Windows identity which is the user app is running under. However, when I use impersonation to query AD then I am querying it as the actual user which does have access to AD. I am just guessing here.