# Cannot get LDAP data using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement on IIS hosted app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, directoryservices

I am using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement Package to get users data from LDAP and it works fine on my local machine but on server, it gives error saying:

**An operations error occurred.

```
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()
   at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection.PopulateList()
   at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection..ctor(DirectoryEntry entry, String propertyName)
   at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection.get_Item(String propertyName)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoLDAPDirectoryInitNoContainer()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoDomainInit()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.Initialize()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.get_QueryCtx()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalSearcher.SetDefaultPageSizeForContext()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalSearcher..ctor(Principal queryFilter)
```

**

.NET Core version is 3.1, System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement version is 6.0 and app is hosted on IIS on a VM (IIS version 8.0). The code I am using is:

```
List < ApplicationUser > users = new List < ApplicationUser > ();

using(var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mydomain")) {

  var userPrinciple = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
  using(var search = new PrincipalSearcher(userPrinciple)) {
    var results = search.FindAll().OrderBy(u => u.DisplayName);
    foreach(UserPrincipal domainUser in results) {
      var adUser = new ApplicationUser {
          Email = domainUser.EmailAddress,
          FirstName = domainUser.Name,
          PhoneNumber = domainUser.VoiceTelephoneNumber,
          UserName = domainUser.UserPrincipalName,
          EmployeeId = domainUser.EmployeeId
      };

      if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(adUser.Email)) {
        users.Add(adUser);
      }

    }
  }
}
```

So far I have tried application pool Identity change to Network Service but didnt work.

Comment: Can [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57077252) help you ?

Comment: It looks to me like maybe the reason it works for you locally and not in the server is that you haven't set any credential;s in the PrincipalContext. So it'll be using whichever user it can find. So locally, yours, in IIS whatever the appdomain is running under.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching alot, I found an alternating solution:

```
List<ApplicationUser> users = new List<ApplicationUser>();
       
        using (var root = new DirectoryEntry(_ladapSettings.LDAPPathString, _ladapSettings.UserName, _ladapSettings.Password))
        {
            using (var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(root))
            {
                searcher.Filter = $"(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(|(displayName=*{filter})(displayName={filter}*)))";
                var query = searcher.FindAll();

                foreach (SearchResult results in query)
                {
                    var de = results.GetDirectoryEntry();

                    if(de != null)
                    {

                        var adUser = new ApplicationUser
                        {
                            Email = de.Properties["mail"].Value?.ToString(),
                            UserName = de.Properties["mail"].Value?.ToString(),
                            FirstName = de.Properties["givenname"].Value?.ToString(),
                            LastName = de.Properties["sn"].Value?.ToString(),
                            PhoneNumber = de.Properties["telephoneNumber"].Value?.ToString(),
                            EmployeeId = de.Properties["employeeid"].Value?.ToString()
                        };

                        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(adUser.Email))
                        {
                            users.Add(adUser);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
```

This works fine on both local machine and on server.

Comment: `PrincipalContext` and `PrincipalSearcher` use `DirectoryEntry` and `DirectorySearcher` in the background. I suspect the difference is in your LDAP string. Using `new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mydomain")` would translate to an LDAP string of `LDAP://mydomain`. So if your server doesn't understand the short name of your domain, it wouldn't work. In your new code, if you're using an LDAP string that uses the DNS name of the domain (`LDAP://mydomain.com`) then that would make the difference.

Comment: I do think it's better to use `DirectorySearcher` directly anyway. But you can make your code run much faster by not using `results.GetDirectoryEntry()`. I explain why in an article I wrote about getting better performance while programming against AD: [Active Directory: Better Performance](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/12/15/better-performance-activedirectory.html)

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace shows that the exception is happening in `DirectoryEntry.Bind`, which is when it initially connects to AD. So something must be different between your computer and the server.

Is the domain accessible to the server? Any firewalls preventing access?

Is your computer joined to the domain, but the server is not? If this is the case, try using the full DNS name of the domain in the `PrincipalContext` constructor, if you aren't already (e.g. `mydomain.com` rather than just `mydomain`).

Are you using impersonation on the server? If so, that could be the issue. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21547199/1202807

That is addressing ASP.NET (not Core), but it could be a similar issue.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing that my computer and server might have some connection difference or something like that but issue was something else. Anyhow I used alternate code and its working now. Thanks for valuable answer though.